# What is the correct status code after testing if an e-mail address exists in the database or not?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-code-404, api-design, http-status-codes

We are using a specific endpoint on our API to test if an e-mail address is already registered in our database. When it's not, what would be the right status code to return to the client ?

We cannot take a decision between 404, 204 and 200. There are a couple of articles over the net but all state pros and cons but it's not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

- 200 says that the request was successful
- 204 says that the request was successful AND that the message body included in the response is 0 bytes long.
- 404 says that there is no current implementation associated with the requested resource

Which of these is correct really depends on your resource design.

Consider a database query with a where clause -- if there are no matching rows, then you get SUCCESS, with an empty result set.  So the analogous thing in a HTTP response would be a 2xx status code, and a body that describes an empty set.

If you were using a JSON List as your representation of the set, then the representation would be two bytes long `[]`, and a `200` status code would be appropriate.  If you were using a [json lines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) representation, with each record on its own line, then with no records you would have no lines, therefore a 0 byte representation and `204` would be a good choice.

What about a case where we have a simple web page, that tells you if the email address is registered or not?  If it's registered, the server responds with a `200` message and a html document that tells you about the registration.  If it isn't registered, then you get an html message telling you that the email address isn't registered... and a `200`, because we were able to find the current representation of the resource.

And 404?  404 indicates to the client that there appears to have been a spelling error in the target-uri of the http request -- that there isn't even nothing to find.

It may help to understand that status codes are metadata about the HTTP response, which is to say that they are part of the [application domain of transferring documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s), not about the business domain.  They are there so that *generic* components, like caches, can do interesting things without needing to know any specifics about the domain in question.

Our web API is a facade to make our domain model look like a boring document store.